# Automatic Login using Oauth

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth

I have create a brand new MVC application using the Internet Template. I have set up the application to use Google to login and register.

All of this works as expected.

What i want to know is, is it possible to automatically log the user into the application after he registered,if he is logged into google at that time, in stead of redirecting him to the login page, so that he clicks the "Login with Google" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that you're always going to be logging in with Google (and no other provider), you can set the redirect to go to the target of the "Login with Google" button. Just look at the link target (`href`) of that button, and change your redirect for unauthenticated users to use that URL instead of the login URL. (You just have to make sure that it'll still be possible for a new user to register. :))

Comment: Thanks, for some reason i expected a very complex solution.I ended up adding a cookie the first time you log in with google.Then when you go to the login page if the cookie is there it redirects to the exteralAuthentication method otherwise to the normal login page.

Comment: @Captain0: can you share your code. I'm interested in your solution.

Comment: Sorry @Captain0, I don't have any code available at the moment. If you have Visual Studio 2012 or 2013, you can just create a new Internet Application from the New Project templates for ASP.NET, and follow the steps I outlined. That should give you the code you want.